# creating website order form

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm trying to create an order form on my website for our customers. What i'm trying to do is list the customers' products in a drop down and then have a text field next to the drop down for qty followed by an add product button. What I am trying to do is once they click the add product button it will add the pair to an array then display their current items in a table below. I'm at a loss as to how to do this. I know I can refresh the page each time they click to add a product for the table display but how do I pass the array to itself? I saw a couple of ways to do this with Coldfusion using URLencoding but seeing as how our customers usually have MANY products per order this would create too long of a url and could cause problems. I also tried looking into using javascript to add to the array and re-display the array without refreshing but I could not find a suitable method of doing this.

My question is this: Am I going about this the right way? Can it be done using javascript and if so how? Or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:
I tried using datatables as it looked like a very promising option but i can't get it to work. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );

function fnClickAddRow(dropdown,textfield) {

    var myindex  = dropdown.selectedIndex
    var SelValue = dropdown.options[myindex].value

    var textvalue = textfield.value

    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        SelValue,
        textvalue] );
}
```

And then I have a form with a button that call the functions onClick as so:

```
input name="Continue" type="submit" value="Add Product" onClick="fnClickAddRow(ProductsDD,Qty);"
```

this won't work though. Any idea as to why? The table is defined as follows as well:

```
table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery datatables. You can add rows dynamically to it without refreshing page. Use fnAddData API. Details : datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: jqGrid is also a quite nice option.

Comment: @Jake: I never used it or may be I am in love with datatable :)